# Reading file names from a directory

Tags: c++, directory

I'm reading all file names from a certain directory using this function:

```
void getdir(std::string dir, std::list<std::string>& files)
{
    DIR *dp;
    struct dirent *dirp;

    if((dp  = opendir(dir.c_str())) == NULL)
    {
        std::cout<< "Error: path "  << dir << " onbekend!\n";
    }
    else
    {
        while ((dirp = readdir(dp)) != NULL)
        {
            files.push_back(std::string(dirp->d_name));
        }
        closedir(dp);
    }
}
```

When I print them out, I get '.' or '..' too with the filenames. But the file '.' or '..' is not in the directory. 
I'm using ubuntu 12.04 :)

Comment: Yes they are. Try `ls -la`. `.` is an alias for the current directory and `..` an alias for the parent.

Comment: @user2321611 - you did not ask a question.

Comment: And what's your question then?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`.` is current directory, and `..` is parent directory, you will find them in every directory.